# Powershell to output results to CSV of AD query for a particular OU

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I have a list of users and and I need to query whether or not they are in a particular OU or not.  I have a Powershell that gives me the nearly the exact results I want in the console, but I would like it written to CSV file instead.  Could someone please help me with the syntax.

```
$Usernames = Get-Content -path .\Usernames.txt

# Running against user list
ForEach ($Username in $Usernames)
{
$ADuser = Get-ADUser -identity $Username –properties *
$UserOU = $ADuser.CanonicalName.ToString().Split('/')[2]

        if ($userOU -match "OUName_A") {
            $OU = "FriendlyOUName_A"
            write-host $Username $OU -foregroundcolor green
        }
        elseif ($userOU -match "OUName_B") {
            $OU = "FriendlyOUName_B"
            write-host $Username $OU
        }
        else {
            write-host $Username "Disabled" -foregroundcolor red
        }
}
```

So the screen output now looks like:

```
username#1 FriendlyOUName_A
username#2 FriendlyOUName_B
username#3 disabled
Get-ADUser : Cannot find an object with identity: 'username#4' under: 'DC=subdomain,DC=company,DC=com'.
At C:\temp\FindOUofUsers.ps1:8 char:11
+ $ADuser = Get-ADUser -identity $Username –properties *
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (username#4:username#4) [Get-ADUser], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Cannot find an object with identity: 'username#4' under: 'DC=subdomain,DC=company,DC=com'.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

It would be helpful to capture the error state as `username#4 Deleted`

Comment: Right now you are just outputting text to the screen. What information would you want in the CSV? How would you want it organized? Two columns, one for Name, and one for...? Status? Do you want more info output to the file?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I'm looking to get two columns, One for Username and one for Status.  The status will be either the FriendlyOUNameA/B, Disabled, or Deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As TheMadTechnician pointed out, you are just outputting text to the screen (and *not* `stdout`).  That's the job of Write-Host.  If you want to write to `stdout`, you should use Write-Output, or simply output the string.

But an even *better* way is to output objects, instead of strings.  That's where the PowerShell pipeline shines.  Once you have actual objects, you can do whatever you want with them -- print them, sort them, and yes, even write them to a CSV file.

This should do what you want.  Note that the script creates custom objects with two properties (UserName and OU).  The objects then get returned to the pipeline, which then gets piped to the Export-Csv commandlet.  I urge you to try the script without the Export-Csv part first -- this will dump the output to the screen, and you'll see what's going on.

```
$Usernames = Get-Content -path .\Usernames.txt
$Usernames | ForEach-Object {
    $Username = $_

    $returnObj = New-Object PSCustomObject
    $returnObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name UserName -Value $Username
    $returnObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name OU       -Value 'Deleted'

    try {
        $ADuser = Get-ADUser -Identity $Username -Properties CanonicalName -ErrorAction Stop
        $UserOU = $ADuser.CanonicalName.ToString().Split('/')[2]

        if ($userOU -match "OUName_A") {
            $returnObj.OU = "FriendlyOUName_A"
        }
        elseif ($userOU -match "OUName_B") {
            $returnObj.OU = "FriendlyOUName_B"
        }
        else {
            $returnObj.OU = "Disabled"
        }
    }
    catch { }

    $returnObj  # This returns the object to the pipeline

} | Export-Csv '.\myFile.csv' -Encoding ASCII -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I will give this a try in the morning.  This looks like what I am wanting to do.

Comment: This is exactly where I was going other than I would have converted the `If/ElseIf/Else` to a `Switch` (one lesson at a time is good though). That was well explained JamesQMurphy, and your modifications of his code easy to follow. That's an answer I'd be proud of if it were mine.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician thank you!  And yes, the switch statement is better, but just like you said, one lesson at a time.

Comment: @JamesQMurphy Works perfectly.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I will research using `Switch` versus the `If/Else If/Else` logic as I would like to more efficiently code these types of problems in the future.